# adobe air with javascript and html

Tags: air, adobe

Hi all i am working on adobe air with javascript and html. I want to open print dialogbox for print the page on the button click event and load this page to print.please help me

Answer (score 0):

Print dialog opens when [PrintJob](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html).start() is called. If it returns true, user has confirmed printing, if false - canceled.